# Creating a hover overlay on an image, but cant seem to make it correct size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create some cards with a hover overlay effect on the image, but can't seem to get the overlay to fit the size of the image. Anyone got any ideas?

http://codepen.io/SRBET/pen/peXooX

Thanks for your help!

```css
.flexWrapper {
 max-width: 1280px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}
.card {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin: 5px;
 max-width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 16px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.card:hover {
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.card img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.overlayContainer {
 position: relative;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.overlay:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.overlayText {
 color: white;
 
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-right: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card h1 {
 font-size: 1rem;
 margin: 2.5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.card p {
 margin: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexWrapper">
  
  <div class="card">
   <div class="overlayContainer">
   <div class="overlay"><h1 class="overlayText">Lorem Ipsum</div>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/640x320"> 
   </div>
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
   <div class="overlayContainer">
        <div class="overlay"><h1 class="overlayText">Lorem Ipsum</h1></div>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/640x320">
   </div>
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display:block; to the img.

```
.card img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:block;

}
```

Comment: You are a saviour. So simple, I think I was looking too much into it. Thank you!